# What to do to stop Express.js from duplicating long multipart requests?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, amazon-s3, multer

Consider the following code:

```
var routes = function(app) {
    app.post('/api/video', passport.authenticate('token', authentication), video.createVideo);
}

function createVideo(request, response) {
  logger.info('starting create video');
  upload(request, response, function(err) {
    logger.info('upload finished', err);
    //callback omitted for brevity
  }
}
```

Upload is multer with multer-s3 middleware:

```
var upload = multer({
  storage: s3({
    dirname: config.apis.aws.dirname,
    bucket: config.apis.aws.bucket,
    secretAccessKey: config.apis.aws.secretAccessKey,
    accessKeyId: config.apis.aws.accessKeyId,
    region: config.apis.aws.region,
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, req.user._id + '/' + uuid.v4() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
  }),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1000000000
  },
  fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
    if (!_.contains(facebookAllowedTypes, path.extname(file.originalname))) {
      return cb(new Error('Only following types are allowed: ' + facebookAllowedTypes));
    }

    cb(null, true);
  }
}).fields([{
  name: 'video',
  maxCount: 1
}]);
```

The code above does the following: it takes a file that is sent from somewhere and streams it to AWS S3 instance. multer-s3 uses s3fs in the background to create write stream and send the file as 5MB multiparts.

With big files, like 300MB it can take minutes to upload. And now something really strange happens. I can see in our frontend that it sends only one POST request on /api/video. Actually I also tried using Postman to make the request, not trusting our frontend.

It starts the upload, but after around 2 minutes it starts 2nd upload! If I try to upload smaller files, like 2-100MB then nothing of sorts happens. This is from my logs(from the code above):

> {"name":"test-app","hostname":"zawarudo","pid":16953,"level":30,"msg":"starting create video","time":"2015-12-02T14:08:22.243Z","src":{"file":"/home/areinu/dev/projects/test-app-uploader/backend/app/services/videoService.js","line":169,"func":"createVideo"},"v":0}
>
> {"name":"test-app","hostname":"zawarudo","pid":16953,"level":30,"msg":"starting create video","time":"2015-12-02T14:10:28.794Z","src":{"file":"/home/areinu/dev/projects/test-app-uploader/backend/app/services/videoService.js","line":169,"func":"createVideo"},"v":0}
>
> {"name":"test-app","hostname":"zawarudo","pid":16953,"level":30,"msg":"upload finished undefined","time":"2015-12-02T14:12:46.433Z","src":{"file":"/home/areinu/dev/projects/test-app-uploader/backend/app/services/videoService.js","line":171},"v":0}
>
> {"name":"test-app","hostname":"zawarudo","pid":16953,"level":30,"msg":"upload finished undefined","time":"2015-12-02T14:12:49.627Z","src":{"file":"/home/areinu/dev/projects/test-app-uploader/backend/app/services/videoService.js","line":171},"v":0}

As you can see both uploads end few ms after each other, but the second one starts after 2 minutes. The problem is - there should be only one upload!

All I did in postman was set my access token(so passport authorizes me) and added a file. This should create only 1 upload, meanwhile 2 happen, and both upload the same file.

Also, notice that both files get uploaded, both have different uuids(notice filename function creates the file names from uuid), both appear on s3, and both has proper size of 300MB, both can be downloaded and both work.

If the upload is smaller the duplication doesn't occur. What is the reason for this behavior? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very simple(I only spent whole day on figuring it out). It's just default timeout of node requests - 2 minutes. I don't know why  it started another one nor why it actually worked, but setting default timeout on my server to 10 minutes fixed the issue.

If someone knows why the timed out requests actually did complete(and twice) please let me know. I'll improve the answer then.